# Cannot connect via Mac OS X 10.6.2 & iPhone to VPN from LinkSys WRT54G

Tags: windows, macos, vpn, iphone

I am at a site that uses a Linksys WRT54G v8.0.0.7 router connected to an Insight Communications cable modem.

I cannot connect to my Windows 2003 PPP VPN via OS X or my iPhone. Both report: "You were disconnected by the communication device. Try reconnecting. If the problem continues, verify your settings."

Both VPNs work just fine on a variety of other routers/configs, it's just something odd with this setup.

I've checked and all of the VPN pass-thrus are set to "Enabled". I don't see anything in the config that would prohibit VPN connections (no custom access rules, forwards, etc).

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Apple's VPN client isn't particularly good at connecting to non-Apple VPNs. If you want to learn the ins-and-outs of racoon configuration, you can sometimes get it to do what you want, but most people just use other products like VPNTracker.

http://www.equinux.com/us/products/vpntracker/index.html

Comment: Non-Apple VPNs? You're referring to the VPN "feature" in Mac OS X Server?

Comment: Actually, I believe the phrase "Non-Apple VPNs" would have to refer to every VPN server in the known universe except the one in Mac OS X Server.